# Inconsistent behavior of conversion to/from locales

Tags: excel, vba, locale, decimal-point

I'm noticing strange and anoying behavior in excel probably due to the different number notation in Belgium.
When I type this in the immediate window, I get counter-intuitive results:

```
 ?val("0,5")
 0
 ?val("0.5")
 0,5
```

so my workaround is to use it like this (normally the string *"0,5"* is replaced by *textbox.value*)

```
 val(replace("0,5",",","."))
```

Also when using the numberformat() function this get me into this kind of troubles.

At first I had a the KeyPresses in the textbox limited like this:

```
Select Case KeyAscii
  Case vbKey0 To vbKey9, vbKeyBack, vbKeyClear, vbKeyDelete, vbKeyLeft, _
  vbKeyRight, vbKeyUp, vbKeyDown, vbKeyTab, vbDecimal
  Case Else
    KeyAscii = 0
    Beep
  End Select
```

But the vbDecimal would only allow me to enter '.'  as a decimal point and then at runtime it would be interpreted as times 1000 the value.

Any light on this ?

Comment: +1 for teaching me how to use Immediate Window to code evaluation!

Answer (score 2):

The `Val` function only recognises "." as decimal separator (as you can read in the corresponding [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k7beh1x9%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)); equivalent thing happens with other VBA functions. Thus, if you modify the decimal separator being accounted by VBA/Excel, quite a few functions wouldn't care (and would continue using "." anyway). What I usually do is setting up a custom function which analyses all the input data (it can consist just in the basic `Replace` you are referring in your question; but I also take advantage from this and adapt the number format to the one I am expecting, for example: maximum number of decimal positions), making sure that all the decimal separators accounted during the calculations are ".". Once all the calculations are done, I have another function to adapt the outputs to the expected format (via modifying the Excel cell or the numeric variables themselves). It is not the ideal situation neither a too-difficult-to-be-fixed problem if you know it.

Answer (score 1):

***Edit***
Found a good example [here](http://vbnet.mvps.org/index.html?code/locale/localenumerics.htm) of overriding 'Regional Locale Numeric Settings'

You could try to accomodate either European or USA seperators by looking at the local environmental variables.

```
'Locale support
Private Declare Function GetLocaleInfo Lib "kernel32" Alias "GetLocaleInfoA" (ByVal Locale As Long, ByVal LCType As Long, ByVal lpLCData As String, ByVal cchData As Long) As Long
Const LOCALE_ICOUNTRY = &H5         '  country code
Const LOCALE_SENGCOUNTRY = &H1002      '  English name of country
Const LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT = &H400
```

Then in your code do somthing like this:

```
If getLocale <= 1 Then  'US
  'use commas
else 'UK
  'use period
End If
```

I'm sure there is a more efficient method but if your loading a dll you can now have two different dll's load depending on your support.

Answer (score 1):

Here in Brazil we have the same number notation ("," as decimal separator, "." as thousands delimiter). I normally use `CDbl()` to convert numbers because it takes into account the regional locale setting.
As you already put out, `val()` is too inconsistent for any real world use for me. It gets easily confused with the commas and dots.

This is what I get with each function. Remember that the value is returned in the regional setting (in this case, comma as decimal separator), but internally it's independent of the notation.

```
? val("2.500,50")
 2,5 
? cdbl("2.500,50")
 2500,5
```

Here, `val()` stops reading the string on the comma - thus reading only "2.500", and considers the dot as a decimal separator. On the other hand, `CDbl()` recognizes the number completely.

```
? val("2,500.50")
 2     
? cdbl("2,500.50")
 2,5005
```

And here, everything becomes a mess as you can see... once again `val()` stops reading on the comma (even though the number is in US notation), and `CDbl()` gets confused with the "misplaced" thousands delimiter after the decimal separator and just ignores it.

Answer (score -1):

```
            Public Function GetNumber(ByVal Subject As String, ByVal Default As Double) As Double
            GetNumber = Default
            On Error GoTo EndNow
            Subject = Replace(Subject, ",", ".")
            Subject = Trim(Subject)
            Dim SplitArray() As String
            SplitArray = Split(Subject, ".", 2)

            Dim FirstNumber As Double
            Dim SecondNumber As Double

            SecondNumber = 1

            Dim IndexOne As Long
            Dim IndexTwo As Long
            Dim PowerLength As Long

            IndexOne = LBound(SplitArray)
            IndexTwo = UBound(SplitArray)
            FirstNumber = CDbl(SplitArray(IndexOne))
            GetNumber = FirstNumber

            If (IndexTwo > IndexOne) Then
                SecondNumber = CDbl(SplitArray(IndexTwo))

                PowerLength = Len("" & CDbl("1" & SplitArray(IndexTwo)))
                PowerLength = PowerLength - 1

                If (FirstNumber < 0) Then
                    SecondNumber = SecondNumber * -1
                End If
                GetNumber = GetNumber + (SecondNumber / Application.WorksheetFunction.Power(10, PowerLength))
            End If



            EndNow:
            End Function
```